# Google Chrome + Proxy on Ubuntu = problems

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, proxy

I am trying to run google chrome with a proxy server on my Ubuntu environment and cannot get this working. Here is my command:

`google-chrome --proxy-server="http://111.111.111.111:111"`

I can connect using this same command on my local (mac) machine, whatismyip.org shows the ip address of the proxy and everything is dandy. On the Ubuntu server, I simply get a timeout. I have tried several different proxies and cannot get this working.

Is there a default security setting on a fresh ubuntu install that would prevent me from being able to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like my proxy was blocking my server IP. Ubuntu is fine, carry on.

Answer (score 0):

Check your proxy, because command is working.

```
google-chrome --proxy-server="http://xxxxx:port"
```